# Accessing the body of the response object

Tags: javascript, json, object

I am having what I think is a pretty trivial problem but somehow I can't find a solution to. I have a response body that looks like this:

```
{
    "sizes": [
        {
            "43": 35
        },
        {
            "42": 20
        },
        {
            "38": 10
        }
    ]
}
```

where the keys are shoe sizes and the value is quantity of each size. How do I access the sizes? What I currently have is this:

```
const sizesArray = response.data.sizes

const arr = Object.values(msizes);
    console.log('arr', arr);
    arr.map((i,a) => {
        console.log('i',i);
        console.log('a',a);
    })
```

but i is then again a object `{43: 35}`
and a is just the index. I want somehow to assign the key to parameter called 'sizes' and the key to a parameter called quantity.

[image: Edit confident-ishizaka-rqjvbv]

Comment: `Object.values` and `Object.keys` get the values and keys (respectively) of an object. You're passing an array to it. When you do this, the keys are the indexes, and the values are the values corresponding to said indexes. There are 2 options that I would consider. The first, which is probably the best, would just be to change `sizes` from an array to an object and get rid of all the inner objects. Your code would work then. This would also make the payload smaller. Second, you can use a `for` loop to iterate through the array, get the keys and values, then push them all to a single array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys), a bit simpler than [Object.entries](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

Example:

```js
const data = { sizes: [{ "43": 35 }, { "42": 20 }, { "38": 10 }] };

const result = data.sizes.map((element, index) => {
  let obj = Object.keys(element); // returns an array of keys
  let key = obj[0]; // first element is the only key
  let quantity = element[key]; // bracket notation, key is an string, not number
  console.log("size", key);
  console.log("quantity", quantity);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just iterate the `sizes` array, using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to append the keys of each object to an output array of sizes:

```js
const data = { sizes: [{ "43": 35 }, { "42": 20 }, { "38": 10 }] }

const sizes = data.sizes.reduce((acc, s) => acc.concat(Object.keys(s)), [])

console.log(sizes)
```

If you want sizes and quantities, you can take a similar approach, just generate an object which accumulates both sets of values:

```js
const data = { sizes: [{ "43": 35 }, { "42": 20 }, { "38": 10 }] }

const { sizes, quantities } = data.sizes
  .reduce((acc, s) => {
     acc.sizes = acc.sizes.concat(Object.keys(s))
     acc.quantities = acc.quantities.concat(Object.values(s))
     return acc
   },
   { sizes : [], quantities : [] })

console.log(sizes)
console.log(quantities)
```

Answer (score -1):

You were on the right track :)

Use `Object.keys()` to get an array of your keys (shoe-sizes). Then use the `map()`-function to create a new array. Use the index of `map()` to access the quantity in your response.

```js
const sizesArray = response.data.sizes

const sizes = Object.keys(sizesArray);
const result = sizes.map((element, index) => ({
  size: element, 
  quantity: sizesArray[index]
}));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Have you tested this code? There are a lot of problems with it. First, `msizes` does not exist (I know it doesn't in the OP's post either, but still relevant). Your `sizes.map` is syntactically invalid, and even if it was valid, `size` would be the index and `quantity` would be `undefined` (you're running `Object.keys` on an array, not an object). Also this isn't necessarily a problem, but I would refrain from making everything a constant. It makes it impossible to run the code more than once.

Comment: Hi Jesse, thank you for your input. I corrected my upper example regarding to the map syntax and the variable name, you are absolutely right about that.
I guess one could argue about the use of constants here. I just left it the way it was in OPs code, to make it easier to follow along.
Using Object.keys on an array is part of Object.keys() documentation for example at mozilla (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys?retiredLocale=de)

Comment: I appreciate the improvement, but it still isn't what the OP asked for. `Object.keys` does have examples of using it on arrays in the docs, but it doesn't work the way you're thinking. As I stated before, the keys are the indexes, and the values are the values in the array corresponding to said indexes. This means `element` and `index` are effectively the same number in every case, and `quantity` is being set to the entire object at that index (I was wrong about it being `undefined`). They're not being split. This is an array of objects but you're treating it as if it's a normal object.